# Dependency in rootpreferences Android Studio

Tags: java, android, dependencies, radio-button, android-preferences

I have a problem with dependency in root_preferences.xml in android studio. I want to add simple settings to my app but some of them will work only if you're a female or a male.

So I have simple CheckBoxPreference right here

```
<CheckBoxPreference
            app:key="pregnant"
            app:title="Pregnant"
            app:defaultValue="false"/>
```

and it should be enabled only if radiobutton on first activity was checked when you were submitting your gender

```
 <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/Female"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="Female"
        android:buttonTint="@color/black"/>
```

so how can I disable this CheckBoxPreference for men and enable it for woman?

Comment: Disabling a `RadioButton` is very easy, but your question lacks lots of information. What is that _first activity_ ? Is it a Sign In page ? Where is the information saved ? Is the gender stored in `root_preferences.xml` ?

Comment: I want to disable the checkbox preference if a user is men, I tried to save boolean in sharedpreferences but I don't know how to disable checkboxpreference from code, not from xml

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

First, you have to save whether the user is male/female.

```kotlin
    // Create class/object to store your Keys
    object KeyConstants {
        const val KEY_IS_FEMALE = "isFemale"
    }

    // Somewhere in your First Activity
    val isFemale = femaleRadioButton.isChecked
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            sharedPrefs.edit()
                .putBoolean(KeyConstants.KEY_IS_FEMALE, isFemale)
                .apply()
```

Then read it in your `PreferenceFragmentCompat`:

```kotlin
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)

            val sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            val isFemale = sharedPrefs.getBoolean(KeyConstants.KEY_IS_FEMALE, false)

            // This will make it enabled when female and disabled when male
            preferenceScreen.findPreference<CheckBoxPreference>("pregnant")?.isEnabled = isFemale
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Radio Group to select one radio button..according to this you can check which radio button is selected male or female  you can show or hide which you want

Comment: The `RadioButton` and `CheckBoxPreference` are not in the same screen. I think you misunderstood que question.

Comment: This is not complex to manage this.I have just shared way, so Please pass the male or female status from activity first to second through intent.putextra("gender",selectedgender) method if radio button and checkbox preference not in same screen.just need to update your checkbox preference  in second screen.